# How to add additional rights to use PDF documents?

Tags: pdf, viewers

I am unable to change the preferences of the Adobe Reader 9.0 (I am using Ubuntu 11.04 Natty Narhal). The preferences are blocked, and when I try to change anything the following message appears:

"Only available when document rights are enabled".

I would like to insert new buttons on the toolbar, deactivate the "Open documents in tabs" and change the pagelayout to double page. So far, I have been unable to make those changes and any changes to the Adobe Reader Preferences because they are blocked and the sentence above appears whenever I try to change anything.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [documentation](http://www.tug.org/applications/hyperref/manual.html#x1-90003.5) for the [`hyperref` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)?

Comment: yes, but not resolve. the problem is adobe reader.

Comment: Have you tried updating to 9.4.2?

Comment: yes, but it did not work.

Comment: How is this a question about TeX/LaTeX?

Comment: I would ask in the Adobe forums.